# How to fix the build sass file from Nebular Auth

Tags: angular, authentication, sass, module, nebular

If you try just install `Nebular Auth Module` probably you is face this error below.

```sh
Error: ./src/styles.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined mixin.
  ╷
5 │ ┌ @include nb-install() {
6 │ │     @include nb-theme-global();
7 │ │     @include nb-auth-global();
8 │ │ };
  │ └─^
  ╵
  src/styles.scss 5:1  root stylesheet
```

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to create an `src/themes.scss` file like this:

```
@import '~@nebular/theme/styles/theming';
@import '~@nebular/theme/styles/themes/default';

$nb-themes: nb-register-theme((), default, default);
```

and to add this import in `src/styles.scss`:

```
@import 'themes';

@import "~@nebular/theme/styles/globals";
@import '~@nebular/auth/styles/globals';

@include nb-install() {
    @include nb-theme-global();
    @include nb-auth-global();
};
```

Make sure you have `nebular theme css` imported in `angular.json`:

```json
"styles": [
    "node_modules/@nebular/theme/styles/prebuilt/default.css",
    "src/styles.scss"
],
```

Answer (score 0):

ANGULAR V15.0.0

do not use "~"

src/themes.scss

```
@import '@nebular/theme/styles/theming';
@import '@nebular/theme/styles/themes/default';

$nb-themes: nb-register-theme((), default, default);
```

src/styles.scss

```
@import 'themes' as*;

@import "@nebular/theme/styles/globals";
@import '@nebular/auth/styles/globals';

@include nb-install() {
    @include nb-theme-global();
    @include nb-auth-global();
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).